# Converting SAS date to month indexing system

Tags: date, sas

How can I convert the month and year of a date to match a variable named by a month indexing system used in a study where January 1986 is month 1? I need to create a variable that calculates the difference between the current month and Jan 1986 but am not sure how to get started. My dates are currently in YYYYMMDD format.

Answer (score 1):

The `intck` function tells you how many intervals of something occur between two dates.

```
monthnum = intck('month','01JAN1986'd, surveydate);
```

If you only have month/year, you can use the `mdy` function to construct a date.

```
dtvar = mdy(monthvar,1,yearvar);
```